# Spritekit- Scene transition Delay

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a main screen which has a button, when this button is pressed it should transition immediately to another scene, but it doesn't. It actually takes a few seconds. Is there a way that I could load all the nodes in that scene beforehand? (Example: in the games load screen)

This is my code:

```
let pressButton = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "playButtonP.png"))

            let buttonPressed = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.15)

            let buttonNormal = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "playButton.png"))


            let gameTrans = SKAction.runBlock(){
                let doors = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration(0)
                let levelerScene = LevelerScene(fileNamed: "LevelerScene")
                self.view?.presentScene(levelerScene, transition: doors)
            }

        playButton.runAction(SKAction.sequence([pressButton,buttonPressed,buttonNormal,gameTrans]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could preload the `SKTexture`s you're using in `LevelerScene` before presenting the scene. Then, once the loading has finished you would then present the scene. Here's an example from the Apple's Documentation, translated to Swift:

```
SKTexture.preloadTextures(arrayOfYourTextures) {
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

In your case you have a couple of options:

**1.**
Keep an array of the textures, which you need to use in `LevelerScene`, that you preload in `GameScene`:

```
class LevelerScene : SKScene {
    // You need to keep a strong reference to your textures to keep
    // them in memory after they've been loaded.
    let textures = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tex1"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "Tex1")]

    // You could now reference the texture you want using the array.

    //...
}
```

Now in `GameScene`, when the user presses the button:

```
if let view = self.view {
    let leveler = LevelerScene(fileNamed: "LevelerScene") 
    SKTexture.preloadTextures(leveler.textures) {
        // Done loading!
        view.presentScene(leveler)
    }
}
```

There's no way you can get around having to wait a little bit, but taking this approach the main thread won't get blocked and you'll be able to interact with `GameScene` whilst `LevelerScene` is loading.

You could also use this approach to make a loading `SKScene` for `LevelerScene`. `GameScene` would take you to the loading scene, which would load the textures and then move you to `LevelerScene` once it was complete.

It's important to note that because the reference to the textures is in `LevelerScene`, once `LevelerScene` is `deinit`-ed the textures will be removed from memory. Therefore, if you want to go back to `LevelerScene` you'll need to load the textures again.

**2.** You could use `SKTexture.preloadTextures` in `GameViewController` before any `SKScene`s have been presented. You'd need to keep a strong reference to these textures (perhaps in a singleton) which you could then reference in `LevelerScene` (or anywhere else you needed them in the app).

With this approach, because the `SKTexture`s are stored outside of a scene, they won't be removed from memory when you transition to the next scene. This means you won't have to load the textures again if you leave and then go back to a scene. However, if you've got a lot of textures taking up a lot of memory you could run into some memory issues.

For more information see *Preloading Textures Into Memory* from [Working with Sprites](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, I can preload the textures of a different scene?

Comment: I used the first method but there's still one node that it's taking a while to appear, what could I be doing wrong? Is there a way to pick which textures are loaded first?

Comment: Is it just one node? Are you adding this node in `didMoveToView`? In response to your question, the textures are loaded asynchronously so you won't be able to change the order they load in.

Comment: I just checked and its not just a node but also and .mp3 and all the SKLabelNodes, is there a way that I could load all the nodes? Not just the textures?

Comment: Preloading the atlas's does not fix the issue for me. Every texture is preloaded and yet it still lags for about 1 to 1.5 seconds, the SKTransition isn't shown and it isn't smooth.

Comment: SKLabelNodes have a known issue where if you don't use the correct font name, it takes a second or two for them to display.  Double-check that you are using the correct font name in your SKLabelNode (i.e., "Avenir-Roman" instead of "Avenir").